# Como editar un registro con combobox (select)

Tags: php, html, combobox, html-select

Mi pregunta ya la habían formulado pero aun asi no logro solucionarlo, estoy haciendo un registro de catálogos y cuando los quiero editar necesito que me aparezca un select con options de los tipos de catálogos que existen, solo he logrado que me retorne el catalogo con la opción que ya estaba registrada pero no logro traer los demás registros para poder cambiarlo y actualizar. Los demas campos si se pueden actualizar, lo unico que me falla es el tipo de catalogo

```
        <form action="procesar-actualizar.php" method="POST">
            <table>
                <?php
                    $id= $_GET  ["id"];
                    $sql="SELECT * from mantenimiento_catalogo WHERE id_catalogo = '$id'";
                    $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                    
                    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                ?>
              
                <tr>
                    
                    <input type="hidden"value="<?php echo $mostrar['id_catalogo']?>" name="id_catalogo"></input>
                   
                
                    <td>
                        <select name="" id="">
                            
                            <option> <?php echo $mostrar['IDTABLA']?></option>
                          
                        </select>
                        
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" value="<?php echo $mostrar['DESCRIPCION']?>" name="DESCRIPCION" maxlength="30" required></input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" value="<?php echo $mostrar['CODIGO']?>" name="CODIGO" maxlength="3" required></input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" value="<?php echo $mostrar['ESTADO']?>" name="ESTADO"></input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class= "btn btn-success " type="submit" value="Actualizar">
                        <a href= "catalogos.php"><input class= "btn btn-danger" type="button"  value="Cancelar"></a>
                    </td>
                    
                </tr>
                <?php
                }

                ?>
            </table>
        </form>
```

procesar-actualizar.php

```
<?php
include ("conexion.php");
$id = $_POST ['id_catalogo'];
$categoria = $_POST ['IDTABLA'];
$descripcion = $_POST ['DESCRIPCION'];
$codigo = $_POST ['CODIGO'];
$estado = $_POST ['ESTADO'];


$actualizar = "UPDATE mantenimiento_catalogo SET id_catalogo = '$id', IDTABLA = '$categoria', 
DESCRIPCION = '$descripcion', CODIGO = '$codigo', ESTADO= '$estado' WHERE id_catalogo = '$id'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $actualizar);

if ($actualizar){
    
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'alert("Catalogo actualizado!");';
    echo 'window.location.href="catalogos.php";';
    echo '</script>';
        
    
    
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu select debe estar fuera del While, de lo contrario siempre estarás retornando el último registro.

```php
<select id="txt_id" name="txt_nombre" >
<?php
include ("config.php");
$query = "SELECT id ,nombre FROM tabla ORDER BY nombre ASC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query ) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($conn));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['nombre']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Para no perder el campo seleccionado , solo debes hacer un select de la opción que ya tienes guardada en tu base, juntamente con el nombre del campo y hacer un echo justo antes del While o justo después de la declaración del `<select>` y dejarlo marcado como selected.

```
echo "<option selected value=".$row['id_guardado'].">".$row['nombre_guardado']."</option>";
```

o

```
<option selected value="<?=$row['id_guardado']?>"><?=$row['nombre_guardado']?></option>
```

Comment: No me funciono, sigue sin traerme los otros registros